# Python 3, how to append tuples into list

Tags: python, list, csv, append, tuples

I just started to learn python. I need to store a csv file data into a list of tuples: tuples to represent the values on each row, list to store all the rows. 
The function I have problem with is when I need to filter the list. Basically create a copy of the list with only the ones that met criteria. I have successfully appended all the tuples into a list, but when I need to append the tuples into a new list, it doesn't work.

```
def filterRecord():
    global filtered
    filtered = list()
    try:
        if int(elem[2])>= int(command[-1]): #the condition
                     #if I print(elem) here, all results are correct
        filtered.append(tuple(elem)) #tuples do not add into the list
                                    #len(filtered) is 0
    except ValueError:
        pass


def main():
    infile = open('file.csv')
    L = list()
    for line in infile:
        parseLine() #a function store each row into tuple
    for line in stdin:
        command = line.split() #process user input, multiple lines
        for elem in L:
            if command == 0:
               filterRecord()
```

If I run it, the program doesn't response. If I force stop it, the traceback is always `for line in stdin`
Also, I am not allowed to use the csv module in this program.

Comment: what is the filter criterion?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem when elem[2] more or equal to a number that user inputted

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `import sys` and use `for line in sys.stdin`

Comment: i did import sys

Comment: Did you do `sys.stdin` instead of just `stdin` ? Otherwise, could you post the full error message?

Comment: I did `from sys import stdin`. I am not getting any error message, the program just keeps running until I force close it

Comment: I'm not sure anything is going to force stop the program from accepting inputs unless you force it. Have you tried using Ctrl + Z or Ctrl + D to cancel the input? This should still continue the program

Comment: I'm on a mac and used Ctrl+C, that gives me keyboardInterrupt. I just tried your advise but still the same.

Comment: I don't believe you want the keyboard interrupt because that will kill your program. I believe you want Ctrl + d to define the EOF(end of file) but that didn't work?

Answer (score -1):

You should use python's built-in library to parse csv files (unless this is something like a homework assignment): https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html.

You can then do something like:

```
import csv
with open ('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: "Also, I am not allowed to use the csv module in this program."